# fragment interface method not invoking

Tags: android, android-fragments

i am making a simple fragment communication app but when i run the app it wil say

```
Attempt to invoke interface method 'void com.example.owner.fragcom.fragment_one$OnnamesetListener.setname(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
```

i think the problem with setname method but i did't no what is going to wrong can any one tell me that is the issue i paste my code here below.

```
public class fragment_one extends Fragment {
EditText etd;
Button button;
OnnamesetListener onnamesetListener;


@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_one_layout,container,false);

    etd = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.frag_one);
    button =(Button)view.findViewById(R.id.send);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            String name = etd.getText().toString();
            onnamesetListener.setname(name);
        }
    });
    return view;
}



public interface OnnamesetListener{

    public void setname(String name);


}


@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
           try {

     onnamesetListener = (OnnamesetListener) context;



    }catch (Exception e){}

}
```

}

this is my code for fragment one here i set one edit text and pass that value to fragment two through main activity.

MAin activity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements fragment_one.OnnamesetListener {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

@Override
public void setname(String name) {


    fragment_two f2 =(fragment_two) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_two);
    f2.UpdateInfo(name);

}
```

}

Fragment Two

```
public class fragment_two extends Fragment {

TextView textView;


@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_two_layout,container,false);

     textView = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textView);

    return view;
}

public void UpdateInfo(String name)
{
    textView.setText(name);


}
```

}

can anyone tell me what is the issue  why i got this type of error and what changes i make in my code.
any suggestion is welcome.

Answer (score 0):

The error is saying your onnamesetListener is null, meaning it never got a reference on the OnAttach method.

I would suggest not leaving your catch empty as you don't know if your Listener was successful on attaching, try the below code to see if it tells you any reason why your listener was null.

```
@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);

    if (context instanceof OnnamesetListener ) {
            onnamesetListener = (OnnamesetListener) context;
    } else {
            throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                    + " must implement OnnamesetListener");
    }
}
```

Comment: still crashing saying
Attempt to invoke interface method 'void com.example.owner.fragcom.fragment_one$OnnamesetListener.setname(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference

Comment: you probably want to move your handler outside of onCreateView, as that is before onActivityCreated(Bundle) which "tells the fragment that its activity has completed its own Activity.onCreate()."  and I would use the debugger and step through the process to see where your onnamesetListener is null and when it has a reference.

Answer (score 0):

I your main activity I can't see where are you attaching the fragment_one if it won't be attached onAttach method wouldn't be called the the listener will be null if you are attaching let us see.